# Javascript: what is the purpose of wrapping a ternary condition in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, parentheses

I recently came across the following line of code:

```
var watcherGlobal = (watcherGlobal) ? watcherGlobal : undefined; // crude singleton, todo refactor into function
```

What I do not understand is why is the condition for this ternary operator wrapped in parentheses? I have seen many ternary operators in code before, but this is the first time that I have seen the condition wrapped like this.

Comment: Readability.  That's all in this case.

Comment: The [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) does nothing. You can write `watcherGlobal`, `(watcherGlobal)` or `((watcherGlobal))`, it doesn't make a difference. There is no reason to use it here. (It might make sense to visually group larger condition expressions, but not here).

Comment: i think its because some devs believe its easier to read code like this, it does nothing functionally

Comment: Ok, all of your comments were very helpful. Thanks for the feedback